# How to join four table in sql ..?

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

I have write sql query where i am join four table with student_id is common in all four table .Please tell me what is error in my sql query.i get this error.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'COUNT(CASE WHEN account.status = 'pending' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'pending', ' at line 1

```
SELECT student_branch.level_id COUNT(CASE WHEN account.status = 'pending' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'pending',
        COUNT(CASE WHEN account.status = 'paid' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'paid',
        COUNT(*) AS total FROM student LEFT JOIN account ON student.student_id=account.student_id LEFT JOIN student_branch ON student.student_id=student_branch.student_id WHERE student_branch.level_id!=''  AND student.status = 'ACTIVE'
               AND student_branch.branch_id = '$data' AND account.fee_active = 1 GROUP BY student_branch.level_id
```

Comment: Put comma before count: SELECT student_branch.level_id , COUNT(CASE WHEN accoun...

Comment: The syntax error results from the missing comma. But there is also a semantical error, I think. If a student has two accounts and three branches, your join results in 2 x 3 = 6 rows (because there is no join criteria to link a branch to a specific account). This will have you count rows multifold.

Comment: Please always tag SQL questions with the DBMS used (MariaDB in your case). The delimiter for names is the double quote `"` in standard SQL, not the single quote. So it should be `AS "pending",` or better just `AS pending,` instead of `AS 'pending',`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below - you missed a comma

```
SELECT student_branch.level_id,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN account.status = 'pending' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'pending',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN account.status = 'paid' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'paid',
       COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM student LEFT JOIN account ON student.student_id=account.student_id
LEFT JOIN student_branch ON student.student_id=student_branch.student_id 
WHERE student_branch.level_id!=''  AND student.status = 'ACTIVE'
AND student_branch.branch_id = '$data' AND account.fee_active = 1 
GROUP BY student_branch.level_id
```

Comment: You should be voting to close as a simple typographical error...

Comment: @Nick, sure  I will

Answer (score 0):

Query is correct but comma issue after **student_branch.level_id**

```
SELECT
student_branch.level_id, COUNT(
    CASE WHEN ACCOUNT.status = 'pending' THEN 1 ELSE NULL
END
) AS 'pending',
COUNT(
CASE WHEN ACCOUNT.status = 'paid' THEN 1 ELSE NULL
END
) AS 'paid',
COUNT(*) AS total
FROM
student
LEFT JOIN ACCOUNT ON student.student_id = ACCOUNT.student_id
LEFT JOIN student_branch ON student.student_id = student_branch.student_id
WHERE
student_branch.level_id != '' AND student.status = 'ACTIVE' AND student_branch.branch_id = '$data' AND ACCOUNT.fee_active = 1
GROUP BY
student_branch.level_id
```